# How to insert first item in ListAdapter?

Tags: android, arraylist, listadapter

In android i'm used to Listadapter.In that data loaded from sqlite to arraylist.my code as

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this statement

```
arraylist.add(0,"All");
```

Comment: you fetch the record from database and assign to the arraylist[stinglist] after that add this line

Comment: Here stringList is ArrayList in ArrayList.so "ALL" string cant accept as parm.It will need array list obj.wat can i do